# Trigger navigation before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have [the following code that redirects automatically to the About component when you load the FAQ component](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sound-tez78?file=/src/App.js). This is done using a custom hook that uses `useHistory()` to push a new route to it. The custom hook also returns an empty object. When you don't try to use anything from this object, the code works perfectly and the app redirects to the About component.

But when I try to access a (non-existing) value from the object, I get the `value is null` error. I don't understand why the code even reaches this. Shouldn't the redirect happen before the rest of the component is rendered?

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Link to="/faq">FAQ</Link>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/faq" component={FAQ} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

function useRedirect() {
  const history = useHistory();
  history.push("/about");
  return {};
}

function FAQ() {
  const { value } = useRedirect();
  return <h1>FAQ {value.name}</h1>;
}

function About() {
  return <h1>About</h1>;
}
```

Why does the redirect not happen *before* the `value` is accessed? And how can I make sure that my app redirects before accessing the `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the redirect not happen before the value is accessed? And how
> can I make sure that my app redirects before accessing the value?

The redirect *does* happen before the value is accessed, but that does not mean that the other source code below the redirection code will not get executed. This is how it is in client side routing.

```
function TestComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  history.push("/about");
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("foo"); // <-- will get executed regardless
  }, 3000)

  return "";
}
```

versus if you were to perform, for example, a `window.location.href` server side http request redirection, the execution will depend on your internet speed

```
function TestComponent() {
  window.location.href = "https://example.com";
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("bar"); // <-- will probably not get executed - will depend on your internet speed
  }, 3000)

  return "";
}
```

I hope this clears up some potential misunderstanding of SPA redirections

Comment: That's good to know! Do you know of any way to force a component to perform the navigation *before* rendering?

Comment: I know one of way preventing renders is if `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false. Read [this section on the "Note" area](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render). On the first render, however, I suppose you could just invoke `return` right away in the function after you push to the history (could optionally be based on some condition) - it _technically_ still "rendered", but you could just return (i.e., render), for example, an empty string

Comment: In addition, you could probably just render a [`<Redirect>`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: Using redirects is a pretty good idea! So I take it that a custom hook probably shouldn't be used to redirect?

Comment: I wouldn't say it shouldn't be used in a custom hook. I suppose there is a use case that could promote this type of solution. But, in this scenario, a `<Redirect>` is ideal. In fact, on your CodeSandBox (if you get rid of the errors first), if you go ahead and go to the base path, then click `FAQ`, then click browser back button, you will notice that you won't get redirected back to the base path - you will get stuck on `/about`. This won't be the case if you use `<Redirect>`